# print value in nodejs on console

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am working on nodejs with mongodb. I have one table in mongo with _id and usercount.When i am trying to get the value from database and trying to print on console with console.log(docs). It is printing both _id and usercount. But when i want to try only usercount with console.log(docs.usercount).. it is giving undefined.

```
Uservisitcount.find({},function(err,docs){
 console.log(docs);
```

this is giving output as
   [{"_id":"xyz","usercount":0}]

how i will retrieve value of usercount only.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/

Comment: @BlakesSeven: I think i am using dot notation as specified there. console.log(docs.usercount)

Comment: That is not "dot notation" but simply acessing the property of a JavaScript object and a completely different thing. But I would suggest a reading of the documentation and the tutorial documentation at least. This is the next section on [Limit Fields to Return from a Query](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/)

Answer (score 1):

`find()` methods returns Array. If you want to get single document, you can use `findOne()` method.

So for `find()` method you have to use `data[0].userCount` // if array length is zero, then exception will be thrown.

For `findOne()` method, you can use `data.userCount` // Check data is not null

Answer (score 0):

I have one solution for this,
try this code

```
console.log(docs[0].usercount);
or
console.log(docs.usercount);
```

hope you get output.

Comment: I tried this but not getting output. I am also confused why it is giving output as undefined..